# CWagent not showing in all Metrix

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

HI please help me for my below question,

I have installed cloudwatch agent on my AWs instance by following these documents link:-
[https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/ec2-memory-usage/#:~:text=Simply%20go%20to%20the%20CloudWatch,memory%20usage%20in%20a%20graph](https://www.sentinelone.com/blog/ec2-memory-usage/#:%7E:text=Simply%20go%20to%20the%20CloudWatch,memory%20usage%20in%20a%20graph)

agent is installed it is showing by terminal and also it is running But i am not able to see CWagent in all metrix.can anyone help what is the issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hd1jM.png)

Comment: Probably, try again and see if you missed out anything, better watch a youtube video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=22lzkpra_WU and refer documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/QuickStartEC2Instance.html
It is quite possible that you missed out some configuration or IAM permission.

Comment: Hi Thanks for you help,i have follow all the steps which define in documents.
all configuration is correct as i ahve cross verfiy but i am not able to see CWagent in AWS console.
similarly I have configure with same steps in other instance and it will show and configured properly.

Comment: if the steps are the same then it comes down to networking, make sure the instance is able to reach the CloudWatch endpoint. Any difference between the working scenario and not working scenario? Like are they in different subnet or something?